# Activate account email {{link}}

Tags: emails, user-profile

Looking at the possibility of sending the link in account activation emails to a set page rather than the homepage which {{link}} does so we have:

http://domain.net but they go to http://domain.net/welcome

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, just did a quick look through the docs. Appears that this can be set via the config file.

[Link to documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#activateAccountSuccessPath)

There's also the option to set whether the user is logged in automatically.